# android detect if other app try to open camera show alert dialoge

Tags: android, camera

I want to create an application, and it needs to know when the camera is turned on by other app, whether the camera application is open or if a third party app is using the camera
how can i detect that if other app is try to open the camera . if other app try to open the camera i want to receive any broadcast before open the camera how can i do this.
i have also try this.

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) camera.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but its alwys return true.

Answer (score 3):

There is no broadcast for camera open or not but Camera Avaiability Listener in Camera2 Api, use below code

```
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
            super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
            //Do your work
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
            super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
            //Do your work
        }
    }, mHandler);
}
```

its only 21 and above

For below 21 you can use your code

```
 public boolean isCameraInUse() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can i check which app is using camera ?

Comment: its not possible, only we can check camera avaiable or not

Comment: if any app is using camera in background . then how can we know that?

Comment: you can set null also. if you need to handle that one by using handler, refer this link https://github.com/Zhoudaxie/XieDaDeng/blob/master/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/FlashlightController.java

Comment: to check camera using in background simply call above method. If camera available to your work or camera not available simply show toast to your user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140029/discussion-between-faisal-iqbal-and-magesh-pandian).

Comment: sry faisa iqbal, i will come after come time. for working source use this link. google sample source for camera2 api https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic